# how to add gradient to borders

Tags: html, css

i was wondering if its possible to add gradients to border top without it affecting border right or border left which in this case are transparent. i tried adding a gradient color but it would affect border left and border right im trying to let border left and border right to be transparent

```
#borderone {
        border-top: 33px solid #354658;
        border-left: 33px solid transparent;
        border-right: 33px solid transparent;
        margin: 0 auto;
        min-width: 1277px;
    }
    <div id='borderone'></div>
```

as you can see this is what i want it to do although i want a gradient background color instead of this solid dark blue color http://jsfiddle.net/EHELN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this efect using background for the gradient, and the 2 pseudo elements at the left and right to get the slanted corners

```
 .test {
    border-left: 33px solid transparent;
    border-right: 33px solid transparent;
    height: 33px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, black, blue);
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 42px;
    background-clip: content-box;
    position: relative;
}

.test:before, .test:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 33px;
    height: 100%;
}

.test:before {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, black 50%);
    right: 100%;
}

.test:after {
    background: linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 50%, blue 50%);
    left: 100%;
}
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j77Vj/)

Looks like I missunderstood the direction. Try this to make it the other way (for webkit)

```
 .test {
    border-left: 33px solid transparent;
    border-right: 33px solid transparent;
    height: 33px;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, black, red);
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 42px;
    background-clip: content-box;
    position: relative;
}

.test:before, .test:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.test:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom right;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, black 0, red 32px, transparent 32px);
    right: 100%;
}

.test:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, black 0, red 32px, transparent 32px);
    left: 100%;
}
```

### [demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/j77Vj/2/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j77Vj/1/ i fixed it but from top to bottom and you can still see that the edges are still not corresponding to the gradient color

Comment: Added solution for the vertical direction. For non webkit browsers, just add unprefixed transforms

Comment: The second solution is better althought the last part doesnt seem to align perfectly .. barely visible but works

Answer (score 2):

See this :
http://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/

It is enough for me in my career .

For example:

```
 #borderone:first-child:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:4px;
    background:linear-gradient(to left, #354658, #9EBBDA);
    top:-33px;
    left:-5;
}
```

For your case , you should use `before` & `first-child` pseudo-selectors CSS in the same time.

```
top(in pseudo selector) = -border height = -33 px
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/EHELN/2/

Comment: i tried this once it didnt work at all because it would mess with my transparent right and left border

Comment: it works in a way but it doesnt cover everything fully

Comment: its because i want to get the gradient all over the dark blue area http://jsfiddle.net/EHELN/3/

Answer (score 0):

*if you want to draw a gradient on your border, then you could use border-image or translucide borders with a gradient in bg : **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/axDjE)***

But then :
You can even drop your translucide borders and make it a padding: **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJaHf)**

```
#borderone {
  position:relative;
  padding:33px 33px 0;/* well this is just like transparent borders :) */
  margin: 0 auto;
  height:100px;
  background:linear-gradient(
    to bottom, 
    #354658, 
    #9EBBDA 33px, 
    transparent 33px
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

This is for the background and not the border, but you can likely create the same effect you are looking for by using this tool.